# How to calculate string occurence in racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Write a Racket function red-vs-blue which consumes a list ramble, and produces a string according
to the following rules:

Examples:

```
(red-vs-blue (cons "red" (cons "blue" (cons 5/7 (cons "blue" empty)))))
⇒ "blue"
• (red-vs-blue empty) ⇒ "tie"
• (red-vs-blue (cons 3 (cons 1 (cons 4 (cons 1 (cons 5 (cons 9 empty))))))) ⇒ "tie"
• (red-vs-blue (cons "red" (cons "green" empty))) ⇒ "red"
```

How would I create the main function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the function for each color, store the results and compare them with a conditional:

```
(define (red-vs-blue lst)
  (let ((reds  (calculate lst "red"))
        (blues (calculate lst "blue")))
    (cond ((> reds blues) "red")
          ((< reds blues) "blue")
          (else "tie"))))
```

Same answer, but without using `let` - this will be less efficient than calculating the required values only once:

```
(define (red-vs-blue lst)
  (cond ((> (calculate lst "red") (calculate lst "blue")) "red")
        ((< (calculate lst "red") (calculate lst "blue")) "blue")
        (else "tie")))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering how would i do this with just a conditional, not allowed to use let.